# Pop-OS! set default camera

Tags: linux, gnome, webcam, gnome3, pop-os

I am on a fresh install of Pop-OS! and I have a web cam and capture card plugged in. Sometimes apps will pick up only the capture card as the first and only device (until I unplug it, then the webcam pops up). How can I configure Pop-OS so I can set the webcam to be "default" or index 0 always.

side question, how do I tell pop-os that my microphone is not a sound output option.